# Django REST Framework custom serializer mixin not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using **Django 2.2** and **Django REST framework**.

In the serializer, I want to have few fields only for creating an instance and not for updating. Means, the user won't be able to change the value of that field once created.

Since Django does not provide any default way to do it. I am writing a mixin which when used will use the `create_only_fields` from the serializer **Meta** to remove the fields from the request data with **PUT/PATCH** request.

**serializer_mixin.py**

```
class CreateOnlyFieldsMixin(object):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = super().to_internal_value(data)
        print(data)
        if self.instance:
            # Update request
            print(data)
            for x in self.Meta.create_only_fields:
                if x in data:
                    data.pop(x)

        return data
```

and using in the serializer like

```
class MySerializer(CreateOnlyFieldsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'value'
        ]
        create_only_fields = ['name']
```

But now calling any endpoint, it gives an error

```
Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.
```

Putting `CreateOnlyFieldsMixin` after `serializers.ModelSerializer` gives no error but has no effect of the mixin.

Appending `to_internal_value` directly in the serializer is working as expected.

Comment: This blog will help you, http://blog.qax.io/write-once-fields-with-django-rest-framework/

Comment: Why not to just use different serializer for create and another one for update? in a view's get_serializer_class , you check the method and return corresponding serializer

Comment: @EnthusiastMartin There are many fields in the serializer. And the number of allowed fields are higher than not allowed. Creating a new serializer will need to re-write the fields list in the new serializer, Also while updating any fields or removing one will have to edit at two places. It is easy to disallow 3-4 fields in place of rewriting 15-20 fields.

Comment: @AnujTBE I would just use Meta.fields from one serializer and extend it in the second with fields needed. this way, when you change the main fields, you dont need to change it twice. it is just an idea. But it seems to me easier than to play around with new mixins. But i might be wrong.